# updating form sheet, skip one column after other while refusing to update text items all together

Tags: google-apps-script

I have  multiple_ choice and Text items on each section of google form b, I tried to import data from google sheet. I observed that it works but skip one column after the other and also the text items did not update at all. This is the link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqSjoV-izUNnjaSl9aJa9J8RsGfbpFbH3l77ze-XMbQ/edit?usp=sharing
This  is the whole script below.  Thanks in advance

```
    function createFormFromData() {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    //Get data, number of questions and options info
    var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var numOfOptions = data.length;
    var numOfQs = data[0].length;

    //Get questions
    var questions = sh.getRange(2, 2, 1,numOfQs).getValues();

    //Get options and store in an array
    var allOptions = [];
    for (q=2;q<=numOfQs;q++){
    var options = sh.getRange(3, q, numOfOptions, 1).getValues();
    allOptions.push(options);
    }

    //Create the form
    var form = FormApp.openById("1UHWkwjpssK-D2m8MUEXeSIzX4x3jLTzc-mts8kCExiI");
    var items = form.getItems();
   for (var i = 0; i < numOfQs-1;i++) {
    var value = items[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    var item;
    switch (value.getType()) {
    case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
    var formQ = value.asTextItem();
    formQ.setTitle(questions[0][i]) ;
    break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
  
  item = value.asMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle(questions[0][i]);
    item.setChoiceValues(allOptions[i]);
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This `var options = sh.getRange(3, q, numOfOptions, 1).getValues();` should be `var options = sh.getRange(3, q, sh.getLastRow()-2, 1).getValues();`

Comment: Thanks,  I followed your instruction, but I still observed that it imported column B,D,F while still skipping C,E,G,H,I

Comment: I didn't know if it was the only problem there must be others but I don't have your data so I can't debug your code.  If you can share your data here I could take a look at it but I won't follow links to offsite resources especially spreadsheets.

Comment: Like I said I don't follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: If you want my help you will have to  post it into your question because I don't follow links to offsite resources.